# Data Scraping with beautifulsoup

Tags: html, python-3.x, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to scraping data. I am trying to **scrape** three details from the website - ""
a. date
b. number of customers
c. current outages

For `current outages`, I tried simply-

```
article = soup.find(class_="menu-content")
keyword_section = soup.find(class_="menu-row")

keywords_raw = keyword_section.find_all(class_="total-outages-value menu-info-numbers")
keyword_list = [word for word in keywords_raw]
```

but this doesn't give me the value of `div` {which is a number}.
I want to simply fetch these for last week (historical data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through the link and it is doesn't give the directly as we have to click on the Home button to get the required data. This can be handled with selenium which is a bit big process and addition settings is necessary.

However, I got a better and simple solution using just requests and BeautifulSoup library.

They have provided the API wherein, they are uploading the data using JSON. So, we can directly scrape the JSON and get the required data. Refer to the below code and also the API link.

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

```
url = 'https://outagemap.coned.com/resources/data/external/interval_generation_data/2020_08_14_17_00_30/data.json?_=1597425338718'
request_url = requests.get(url)
json_response = request_url.json()

print('Date:\t\t\t', json_response['summaryFileData']['date_generated'])
print('Number of custormers:\t', json_response['summaryFileData']['total_cust_s'])
print('Current Outages:\t', json_response['summaryFileData']['total_outages'])
```

Refer to the below screenshot for the output.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. This is really helpful. Is it possible to go in backdate? Like I am looking for scraping data since last week onwards.

Comment: I don't think it is possible. Data is being update regularly. So far, I know, I don't think we can get the past data. Good that it helped you. :)

Answer (score 0):

It would have been very much helpful if you have provided the website link that you are scraping and the complete code. However, from the code you have shared, I can say that, you have missed mentioning the attribute that you wanted to scrape ie `soup.find('attribute', class_ = 'some_class')`

For example, if date is under the attribute 'li' then you should mention as

```
soup.find('li', class_ = 'abcd')
```

If number of customers is under the attribute 'div' then you should mention as

```
soup.find('div', calss_ = 'efjh')
```

If this didn't help you, I suggest you to mention the website that you wanted to scrape and also the entire code for use to understand and answer relevant.

Comment: Hi @Sandeep, I have update the post with the website link. Although I don't have a code yet to perform the task.

Comment: @x2212, thanks for providing the link. It helped me though no code was provided. I have explained the details and added the solution in another comment. Hope, that will help you.